# Proving IVT using Axiom of completeness

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am reading abbot and solving its problems. Consider the following problem.

Finish the proof of IVT using the axiom of completeness start previously.[image]

I think was able to do one part. Suppose f(c) > 0, since c = sup K. we know that c can be achieved through a sequence where the elements are in K. More precisely, there exists $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow c$. Since f is continous we should have $f(x_n) \longrightarrow f(c)$. However $f(x_n) \leq 0$ and $f(c) > 0$ contradiction. Thus, $f(c) \leq 0$.

I am having troubles for the case $f(c) < 0$. I think in this case we contradict upper boundness. However, why can we produce a $\delta$ such that $f(t) < 0$ for $V_{\delta}(c)$ using continuity ?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f(c)<0$. Take $\varepsilon = -f(c)/2>0$. Then, by continuity, there is $\delta >0$ such that $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta) \implies f(x) \in (f(c)-\varepsilon, f(c)+\varepsilon) \subset (-\infty,0)$.

In particular, $f(c+\delta) < 0$ and $c$ cannot be $\sup K$.

Comment: Oh alright, awesome thanks a lot.